# Why aren't email abuse reports treated like an optout?

Tags: civimail, bounce-processing

We are using a bounce email account which generally works fine for optout and unsubscribe notices. On our site Civimail is set to send mail out through an Amazon AWS SMTP account. When the recipient clicks a "report spam" button, the bounce account gets an email from complaints@email-abuse.amazonses.com with a body similar to:

> This is an email abuse report for an email message from amazonses.com on Tue, 28 Feb 2023 14:42:39 +0000

Civimail bounce processing then moves this email to INBOX/CiviMail/processed, but it doesn't make any change to the contact record. As a result Civimail continues to send our bulk mail to that contact. It would make more sense to treat an email abuse complaint as an optout. Any suggestions on resolving this?

Edit: this is on civicrm 5.58.1 and wordpress 6.1.1.

Comment: "but it doesn't make any change to the contact record ". How have you tested this. For some bounces it requires 'several' before the threshold is met to put the contact record On Hold.

Comment: Are you using an extension or just the SMTP connection only? AirMail is not recording correctly FWIW: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41661/aws-complaints-not-being-logged-as-spam-bounce-type?noredirect=1#comment50297_41661

Comment: @petednz I tracked a year's worth of abuse reports and looked at the contact records, because we were getting complaints that we are ignoring unsubscribe actions - which turned out to be "report spam" actions. If I am understanding civicrm_mailing_bounce_pattern and civicrm_mailing_bounce_type, abuse reports should be bounce_type 10, which has a hold_threshold of 1.

Comment: @AndyBurns-iXiam no extension, just a SMTP connection.

Comment: We use AWS and receive these similar messages from AOL/Yahoo/Comcast addresses. They are always correctly put on hold, as far as I can tell. 5.58.1 on Drupal 7.